# Scheme-theoretic Preimage and Fibered Product of Schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, pullback

Following Eisenbud-Harris *The Geometry of Schemes*, and I'm having trouble understanding a specific part of their proof that fibered products exist in the category of schemes.

The affine case is okay, no problems there. However, then we go to the general case, where we consider $X, Y$ and $S$ to be schemes with morphisms $\varphi \colon X \to S$ and $\psi \colon Y \to S$. The idea is to cover the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
&&X\\
& @VVV{\varphi}\\
Y @>{\psi}>> S
\end{CD} 
with diagrams
\begin{CD}
&&\mathrm{Spec}\, A_{\rho\alpha}\\
& @VVV{\varphi_{\rho\alpha}}\\
\mathrm{Spec}\, B_{\rho\beta} @>{\psi_{\rho\beta}}>> \mathrm{Spec}\, R_{\rho}
\end{CD} 
and apply the affine case to obtain a family of fibered products of affine schemes and glue them together.

The problem is how they define that. So the $\mathrm{Spec}\, R_{\rho}$ are an affine cover of $S$. Then, **$\mathrm{Spec}\, A_{\rho\alpha}$ and $\mathrm{Spec} \, B_{\rho\beta}$ are the coverings of the preimages of $\mathrm{Spec}\, R_{\rho}$ in $X$ and $Y$ respectively**.

This last sentence is what I don't get. The only time the word *preimage* has appeared before in the book is in the definitions of the preimage of a closed subscheme $X'$ defined by an ideal $I$ of $R$ where $\psi \colon \mathrm{Spec}\, T \to  \mathrm{Spec}\, R$ is a morphism of affine schemes.

> How do I make sense of the sentence in bold?

Comment: $\operatorname{Spec} R_\rho$ is an open subset of $S$, so its topological preimages will be open subschemes of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Closed subschemes are much more subtle that open subschemes. For an open subset there is one and only one possible scheme structure on it making it an open subscheme. Hence the preimage of an open subscheme is just the preimage of the open set with this structure. As there is not just one scheme structure for a closed set you can't do the same for the preimage of a closed subscheme.

Comment: @Yesterdaywasdramatic Thank you very much! It is clear now.